# SETENV: Bad : modifier in $ ($)

Tags: linux, tcsh, setenv

I am using the tcsh terminal in Linux. In the other terminal I normally used I set the path to some license file as follows:

```
  export PATH="$PATH:$MODEL_TECH"
```

Tcsh shell does not recognise this command so I tried the following:

```
  setenv PATH "$PATH:$MODEL_TECH"
  set PATH "$PATH:$MODEL_TECH"
  setenv PATH=("$PATH:$MODEL_TECH")
```

But then I always get the following error:

> Bad : modifier in $ ($).

What be also great if someone could help me here out quickly, tried quite a few combinations but nothing works.

Answer (score 5):

Drop the `=`

```
setenv LICENSE_FILE "/usr/local/softwarex/license.dat"
```

From the man page for tcsh:

```
   setenv [name [value]]

   Without  arguments, prints the names and values of all environ‐
   ment variables.  Given name, sets the environment variable name
   to value or, without value, to the null string.
```

Answer (score 5):

Put curly braces around the variable names:

```
setenv PATH ${PATH}:${foo}
```

or use this form:

```
set path = ($path $foo)
```

Comment: Right.  csh/tcsh uses the `:` character for modifiers; for example `$var:t` gives you the root of the filename `$var` (by deleting the `.whatever` extension).  If you write `"$PATH:$MODEL_TECH"` the shell thinks the '$' is part of a modifier for $PATH (which it doesn't recognize).  The curly braces separate the name from the following `':'`.  The `set path = ...` form sets the corresponding shell variable `$path`, which is tied to the environment variable `$PATH`.  `man tcsh` for more information.

Comment: Although not stated, an explicit string will work as well e.g. `setenv PATH ${PATH}:/foo/bar`

Answer (score 2):

Try `setenv LICENSE_FILE /usr/local/softwarex/license.dat`. This should be documented in the `man` page somewhere on your system, so try reading up in `man tcsh`; `tcsh` is a very different beast from `bash` and friends. If the relevant `man` page isn't available on your system for some reason, here's the first [`man tcsh`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/tcsh/) I found.

Comment: Great, that works fine but it seems there are still problems when I wanna set a path, I added this to my post. I get then a bad modifier error.

Comment: tcsh syntax for setting the PATH is different than sh variants.  Do you have a good reason for using tcsh?  Unless there is a *very* compelling reason, it's probably better to continue using an sh-variant.

Comment: @reinhard Is `$MODEL_TECH` set?

Answer (score 0):

On a tcsh shell the path or any environment variable can be appended as below:

```
setenv PATH $PATH":$NEWPATH"
```

Answer (score -1):

If it's not working use this:

```
setenv PATH ${PATH}:/.../../../
```